# Item packing with real numbers optimization for delivery

Tags: algorithm, optimization

I am just starting my adventure with programming and I encountered a problem that I am not sure if my way of thinking is correct so I seek advice.

We have N items with a volume of x_n and x_n can be double(let's say there are 5 items with volume 1, 2, 3, 3 , 100 etc). As a delivery company we only have trucks with empty space of number 5*k-1 (like 4, 9 ...). I need to find the best way to put those items into trucks to minimize empty space after. I can use as many trucks as I need with any volume I want.

So the question is easy when x_n is just an integer because then we fit items by mod5. But I have no idea how to find a vialable solution when x_n is a real number like 1.567 etc.

Comment: Welcome here, beginner. Kindly help us help you out by showing your effort so far as well.

Comment: The best I can think of for right now is to check all possible trucks up to the size of truck that is => to the weight of all items. So for me it is just forcing an answer with some limitations.

Comment: I don't really need a full answer. Just would like to get a direction where i should be looking for it